# MYSQL - count how many times a person comes second in a competition

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following table called 'players' which contains scores from 3 games played by Tim, Bob and Jon.

```
playid | name | score
1      | Tim  | 10
1      | Bob  | 5
2      | Tim  | 5
2      | Bob  | 10
3      | Tim  | 5
3      | Bob  | 10
3      | Jon  | 4
```

I want to be able to count the number of times that Tim, Bob and Jon have come second i.e. Tim = 2, Bob = 1, Jon = 0.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT name FROM players WHERE playid = 1 ORDER BY score Desc LIMIT 1, 1
```

Which returns the name of the person in second place in the first game i.e. Bob, but I can't figure out how to extend this to cover all games and players. Eventually I also want to be able to count the number of times they come 3rd, 4th etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use ROW_NUMBER()/DENSE_RANK() when using MySQL 8.0+ or simulate it with MySQL's user variables to get group ranks..

Comment: [Get the rank of a user in a score table (dba.stackexchange)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table) or this one [Get the rank of a user in a score table (dba.stackexchange)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213628/mysql-query-to-get-rank-of-a-student)

Comment: Please explain what to do when scores are tied.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following one:

```
SELECT count(playid), name, score
FROM `players` 
WHERE score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM players WHERE score < (SELECT MAX(score) FROM players))
GROUP BY score, name;
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this only works if the 2nd highest score for each playid is the same as the second highest score over all the playids i.e. it is looking for where a player has a score of 5. However if I changed playid 1 to have scores Tim: 12, Bob: 5. Then it will look for where a player has a score of 10 (as this is now the second highest score over all the games), which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query below to find the `secondly-ranked` people :

```
SELECT q2.playid, q2.name
  FROM
  (
   SELECT q1.* , if(switch1,@r:=@r+1,@r:=0) as switch2
     FROM
     (
       SELECT playid, score, name, 
              if(playid=@p,@p:=0,@p:=playid+1) as switch1
         FROM players
         JOIN ( SELECT @p:=0, @r:=-1 ) p2            
        ORDER BY playid, score desc
      ) q1 
   ) q2
  WHERE q2.switch2 = 1
  ORDER BY q2.playid

playid  name
------  ----
1       Bob
2       Tim
3       Tim
4       George
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/VZHCT9437)</kbd>

Comment: @ArifulIslam yes, it was so.

Comment: Thanks Barbaros. I had trouble getting this work at first. For some reason I had to change q1.* to q1.playid, q1.name then it works fine. How would I edit this code to count 3rd places?

Comment: Also could you explain how the if(playid=@p,@p:=0,@p:=playid) part of your code works please. I haven't seen this in mysql before.

Comment: @Tim0thy That's iteration through classical conditional logic like `if playid = @p then @p:=0 else @p:=playid`

Comment: @Tim0thy I've tried more added cases and met some issues and decided to added the switch2 as above, please consider this new one.

Answer (score 0):

With multiple joins and groupings:

```
select pl.name, ifnull(counter, 0) counter from (
  select distinct name from players) pl 
left join (
select players.name, count(*) counter from players
inner join (
  select p.playid, max(p.score) as secondscore from (
    select players.* from players
    left join (
      select playid, max(score) as maxscore
      from players 
      group by playid) p
    on p.playid = players.playid and p.maxscore = players.score
    where p.maxscore is null) p
  group by p.playid
) p
on p.playid = players.playid and p.secondscore = players.score
group by players.name) p 
on p.name = pl.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ttDBYNxk1ECKPXPqXUx6hA/0)

Comment: Thanks, this works. How would I go about extending this to count the 3rd place scores?

Comment: This cannot be extended for that purpose. It targets specifically the number of times each player was 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment by Raymond Nijland, in MySQL 8.0+ you can use window functions to achieve this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS second_place_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        name,
        playid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY playid ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn
    FROM players
) AS ranks
WHERE ranks.rn = 2
GROUP BY name
```

...or if you want to extend this to all places:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    rn AS place,
    COUNT(*) AS place_count
FROM (
    SELECT
        name,
        playid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY playid ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn
    FROM players
) AS ranks
GROUP BY
    name,
    rn
```